# Why am I receiving make errors when trying to compile GCC?

Tags: linux, gcc, makefile, linux-from-scratch

I am currently working on Linux From Scratch part 5.5: http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/stable/chapter05/gcc-pass1.html Although i have followed everything exactly correctly to this point, I am receiving the following make errors after about 20 minutes of compiling GCC 8.2.0:

```
make[3]: *** [Makefile:1110: graphite-isl-ast-to-gimple.o] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory '/mnt/lfs/sources/gcc-8.2.0/build/gcc'
make[2]: *** [Makefile:4567: all-stage1-gcc] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/mnt/lfs/sources/gcc-8.2.0/build'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:21435: stage1-bubble] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/mnt/lfs/sources/gcc-8.2.0/build'
make: *** [Makefile:897: all] Error 2
```

Any help would be appreciated, I have been trying for hours.

Comment: This Q is more appropriate for https://unix.stackexchange.com . Please read the [help](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/How-to-ask) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Comment: Part of the build log you provide only tells that "*something* has been wrong". It is nearly impossible to find what is wrong knowing only these messages. Please, provide **specific error messages** (they comes somewhere before given lines).